# Unable to start SoapUI-pro in linux and error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang

Tags: linux, soapui

[image: Soapui-pro:error]

I ve just downloaded a version of Soapui-pro ie. soapUI-Pro-x32-4.6.0 and i am unable to run it.
And is there any other tools (except postman) for analysing or checking vulnerablities in API's??

Comment: Rees, have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown when you are trying to use incorrect software i.e., using 32-bit software on 64-bit machine or vice-versa.

Suggest you to download and use the correct software for your machine architecture.

Comment: @Reeshunt, if you think the above solution helps to resolves the issue, appreciate if you accept it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed openjdk and everything ok.
for fedora it was

```
sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk
```

for ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```